# Change properties of WebView2 runtime embedded in SAP GUI

Tags: microsoft-edge, abap, webview2, sap-gui, dynpro

SAP uses WebView2 as new browser control.

Is there an API or a possibility to change properties of the embedded webview2 control?

Or is just SAP allowed to the any changes regarding webview2?

Is there maybe something possible with ActiveX, that I can call from HTML inside WebView2?

Comment: Please be precise, which exact property do you want first to change? "Property" could mean many things. What is your exact programming issue? Which programming language do you use? Please add the missing verb in "SAP allowed to the any changes".

Comment: Hey Sandra, I want to change the default zoomfactor (1.0) to 1.5.
I'm using ABAP, a classical Dynpro with CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER as custom_control

Comment: Just for understanding, is the WebView2 integrated in SAP via CFW? E.g. the method GO_BACK of CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER calls the frontend-method GoBack. Where can I see, which frontend-methods exist? Is this something, what Microsoft delivers or does SAP wrapps own methods above WebView2-control? Thank you @SandraRossi

Answer (score 0):

From sap note [2913405](https://%20https://me.sap.com/notes/2913405/E):

- **There are limitations:** "SAP is presently working on making the HTML Control using Microsoft WebView2 Control as compatible as possible. However, since this is a huge new development on both SAP and Microsoft side, it will take a while before all functionality is available. A list of restrictions and issues which are presently known can be found in SAP Note 2901278."
- **Which options do you have to influence which browser is used by SAP GUI for Windows?** Up to and including release 7.60 of SAP GUI for Windows, you have no influence on the browser control used. The only influence you have, is the configuration of the default browser via operating system methods and this only has impact on some scenarios.
  *In SAP GUI for Windows 7.70 and in SAP GUI for Windows 8.00 (and higher) when the browser extension mentioned in SAP Note 3258944 is NOT used, a limited browser window is displayed (msedgewebview2.exe). Only when the browser extension is combined with a new version of SAP GUI for Windows, a full Microsoft Edge window or tab can be opened.